# Lateral View Explode in Spark 2.2 performance issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my use case I have to go for 22 Lateral View Explode. For 1 record i am getting 0.9 Million records after Lateral View Explode. Job is getting failed if i do this for more than 1 record.
Request to put some light on this.